# Отправка txt файла через Intent(намерение) в другое приложение Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, файловая-система, android-intent, uri

Хочу отправить txt файл с директории getExternalFilesDir() другому приложению через Intent, принимает только WhatsApp, в телеграмм, gmail, insta пишут подобное "Вложение не поддерживается"

---

```
         val ExtDir = getExternalFilesDir("dictionary")
         val w_fileWR = File(ExtDir.toString(), "word.txt")

         val GetFileUri = Uri.parse(w_fileWR.toString())

        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, GetFileUri)
        shareIntent.type = "*/*"
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

        if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(shareIntent)
        } else {
            out_error.text="Ошибка!"
        }
```

---

В файл манифеста ничего не добавлял нужно ли?
пробовал ставить тип MIME

---

```
      shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
```

---

еще читал, что при вызове

---

```
        shareIntent.setData()
        shareIntent.setType()
```

---

последняя функция затирает данные записанные первой, поэтому пробовал

---

```
        shareIntent.setDataAndType(GetFileUri, "*/*")
```

---

но тогда вообще нигде не работает, еще мне кажется что неправильно чоздаю Uri для файла
пробовал создавать через FileProvider но не совсем понятно что за поле authority
при вызове

---

val FileUre: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "authority???", w_fileWR)

---

так же пробовал создавать Uri

---

```
        val GetFileUri = Uri.fromFile(w_fileWR)
```

---

но тогда приложение вылетает.
Файл точно есть хоть его наличие и не проверяю, и файл не пустой. Мне кажется нужно какое-то разрешение на чтение из директории для других приложений, но тогда почему при первой версии его читает ватцапп.

Comment: `FileProvider` нужно прописать в манифесте, а "authority???" - та же строка, что вы укажете в атрибуте `android:authorities`, обычно производное от пакета приложения. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing#DefineProvider. Отправку попробуйте по этому примеру: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856167

Comment: вы не можете в Intente передавать путь к файлу, нужны спец разрешения